# git log shows diff despite --no-patch

Tags: git

I'm using Git v2.10.2 (finally an update) on macOS Sierra. I noticed in the `git log` command, whenever I use the `-L` argument to look at specific lines of code of a file, `git log` prints out the diff output even when `--no-patch` is specified clearly. Without the `-L`, it works as it should behaves.

Is there something I'm missing with the `-L` parameter? Thanks!

Sample command:

```
git log --oneline --no-patch -L 1,3:package.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--no-patch` doesn't make sense with `-L` and therefore it is ignored. By providing the `-L` option, you select a range of lines in the specified revision of a file and tell git to show the history of that fragment, which cannot be done without showing diffs.